# Where was the computer skill split up into operation, programming and hacking?

Tags: skills, content-identification, mechwarrior-3e

I just joined a MechWarrior group that uses the old 3rd edition books. I was handed a PreGen from the core book (The Federated Suns Technician)<sup>1</sup>, which lists the "Computer" skill.

However, during play, I was told that in *some later book* (still in the 3rd edition) that skill had been split up into "Operation", "Programming", and "Hacking". Which book is that skill-split in, and does that book also contain a rule on how to adapt a character that was made without that book?

---

1 - MechWarrior 3rd Edition (FASA #1715) (1999) p. 70/71.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was added in [*Classic BattleTech Companion*](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/72297/classic-battletech-companion) (FanPro #10975), an expansion to 3rd edition first published in 2003. The relevant text is on page 107.

> This skill has been revised as a cascading skill that lets a character choose to specialize in various areas of the computer field. For the purpose of roleplaying, the computer skill has been broken down into three areas of specialization: Computer/Operations, Computer/Programming, and Computer/Hacking. Each skill gives the character a working knowledge and a chance to become an expert in the specialization they choose. (INT/WIL)

Comment: That's... FanPro #10975?

Comment: yes, that's the one :)